# how to let child widget process QKeyEvent?

Tags: events, qt4, widget, keypress

I'm using a QTabWidget as centralWidget in a QMainWindow , however , keyPressEvent() won't trigger in any child widget of QTabWidget , if i try the following in that QMainWindow::keyPressEvent() , it will crash.

```
void Window::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e) {
    QApplication::sendEvent( centralWidget->currentWidget() , e );
}
```

Window is an instance of QMainWindow.

What's the correct way to let child handle those events , instead of parent widgets ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the child widget is designed to receive and handle key press events, then it will receive them if it has keyboard focus. If it is a custom or subclassed widget then you will need to do a few other things besides just overriding the child widget's `keyPressEvent()` as described [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#events).